# how to find number if div with a particular background color

Tags: html

Below is the code with a grid.  how to display how many cells with a color yellow and so on
http://fiddle.jshell.net/calsql/L3031nwh/51/

Answer (score 0):

You may first want to "translate" all your hex colors to RGB, and make an object with a counter for every color, initialized in 0. This because what you are getting from the `$(elem).css('background-color')` is an RGB, not a hex.

Then you can iterate over each "pixel" of your canvas and incrementing each color's counter correspondingly.

Something like:

```
let colorCounter = {}
$('fieldset .palette')
    .filter(i => $(i).css('background-color'))
    .each(color => colorCounter[$(color).css('background-color')] = 0)

$('div.canvas div.pixel')
    .each(pixel => if (colorCounter[$(pixel).css('background-color')]) 
                           colorCounter[$(pixel).css('background-color')]++)
```